# In graph theory: Is there a rooted product of trees?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, products

I would like to know from the experts and fellows with experience, as my googling is not returning precisely what I'm searching for but the rooted product of graphs.

My question is whether there exists a formal definition (and properties) for the product of two rooted trees, say tree T1 times tree T2, such that the product yields a tree T3 which corresponds to T1, but the root of T2 is attached to each leave of T1 ??

Have you ever heard about this?

Thanks!

Comment: So the resulting tree $T_3$  is not a tree? (It has a cycle)

Comment: You mean that each leaf of $T_1$ is replaced by its own copy of $T_2$ (attached at the root to the parent of that leaf)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Well, I didn't write it explicitly, but only the leaves of $T_1$ are connected to the root of $T_2$. We maintain the original root of $T_1$. Hence, the resulting $T_3$ is a tree, with a root (same as the root of $T_1$) and new leaves, which happen to be copies of the leaves of $T_2$ rooted in the leaves of $T_1$.